# How do I make a return type of int[][] with a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, return-value

Heres my code:

```
public int getPieceCoords(int entityId) {
    for(int x = 0;x<8;x++) {
        for(int y=0;y<8;y++) {
            if(position[x][y] == entityId){
                return position[x][y];
            }else{
                return (int)null;
            }
        }
    }
    //Need a return here, but it overrides the returns above
}
```

So, I am having trouble getting this to return the actual output I want, help is appreciated!

Comment: What is this - > `return (int[][])null;`?

Comment: `the actual output I want` being what?

Comment: the above returns... I would have to put a return below and it would just reset to what I had below

Comment: What's the problem that you are facing? As per your code it will return at the first iteration only for x= 0 and y = 0...

Comment: O.o.. Wait, you are return an `int` value for `int[][]` return type?

Comment: I do not understand, what are we solving here... I know entityId and I am searching in the array and returning same entityId back if found... If it is search then I must return true or false or index of the entityId... I think someone must tell what question are we solving.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getPieceCoords(int entityId) {
int  temp = 0;
    for(int x = 0;x<8;x++) {
        for(int y=0;y<8;y++) {
            if(position[x][y] == entityId){
                temp = position[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
   return temp;
}
```

Comment: This can't be right, if entityId is an int, and position[x][y] can be compared to it, it must be an int.  How can you cast as int to an int[][]

Comment: oops sorry, i was just changing a few things in the editor cuz it is my first post so i had changed a few things, Yes you are right it is an int in eclipse

Comment: @sunleo, nope still wont compile. The return type is `int[][]`, you're returning an `int`

Comment: I still have an error in my editor that says i need a return statement, I am goin to sleep so Ill check in morning

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
public int getPieceCoords(int entityId) 
{
   int result = -1;
    for(int x = 0;x<8;x++) 
     {
        for(int y=0;y<8;y++) 
          {
            if(position[x][y] == entityId)
               {
                result = position[x][y];
                break;

               }
           }
    }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: That should be `return result` at the end. And why use a `temporary` variable? Just return as soon as you find a value. And at the end `return -1;`

Comment: @RohitJain: It will do the same thing, just creating a temp variable for clarity

Comment: @Sashi.. Yeah I know it will do the same thing. And actually returning at the place will be more clear. But again, its always a personal choice. So, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified to return `int[][]` type in your method but,

`return position[x][y];`

is returning an `int` , you might want to check it.

Edit: According to your new(edited) code, you are returning the same value as of parameter

```
entityId
```

in case of match or `0` if there is no match.

This doesn't make much sense, why not to use Boolean as return type? i.e return `true` on match or `false` otherwise?